# Hippocms Cache warmer

Tags: hippocms, page-caching

Publication changes in cms invalidates whole cache in Hippocms. Is there any best practice to warm cache in hippocms? Cache warmer by scheduler not an option. Is it possible to warm by trigger on cache invalidation?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the page cache its primary goal is to be a hotspot pages cache (for example homepage that is requested 1000 times per second) and it provides a stampeding herd protection (100 requests at the same time request the same page: 1 request is executed, all other requests are served the same response)
Because of cluster requirements and since we do not know on which page which content is used, the page cache is currently very volatile : It would be easy to cache a page for, say, 5 minutes, regardless content changes: However in clustered setups, this can then result for some short period in alternating pages depending on which cluster node you hit: This is not acceptable.

That is how it works now. For 11.1 I already have a *very much* improved page cache solution which still uses the current one but adds a second level page cache (which in general we cluster via redis and on which we also set a TTL for a page) *and* next to the second level cache we provide a stale page cache: The stale page cache is used that if 100 requests arrive for the same page and there is no valid page in primary or second level cache, then 1 request passes and builds up the new page, and all other 99 get the stale response. After the 1 request that passes gets the response back, the stale page cache entry is purged and everybody receives the non-stale page. Note that stale page cache support is possible without a second level cache (and second level cache without stale page support is also possible). 
Another advantage of the second level page cache, is that if you make it clustered (which you should (easy configuration option)), is that only one cluster node needs to create a page response.
Version 11.1 will ship with this improved page cache options. Note that that page cache as it is now, and in the future, works seamlessly with relevance (personalization of pages)

Hope this helps,

Regards Ard

Comment: you said that page cache's primary goal is to cache a hotspot pages. But what will happen if all the available pages be cached?